# Create a Composite Property in an Entity Framework Model?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have two properties ("FIRST_NAME" and "LAST_NAME") I need to access as a single property (e.g. "FULL_NAME"). Is there a way for me to add a property to my entity model that contains the combine value of FIRST_NAME and LAST_NAME?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Since the model classes which are created by EF4 are usually `partial` classes you have the option to extend the classes in a separate file with your additional properties and methods. There you could add a readonly property with only a Getter to return your combined full name:

```
public partial class Person
{
    public string FullName
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Concat(FirstName, " ", LastName);
        }
    }
}
```

This is a property which is only in your model class but not mapped to the database and it doesn't exist as a column in the database. Because you create this part of the partial class in a separate file it is not touched and overwritten by the model designer if you should change the model.

Comment: Thanks, this was really helpful. Unfortunately, I can't use these partial classes with QueryExtenders as DataFields which was where I was headed. :(

Comment: @davemackey: Ah, I see, you want to query for `FullName`, right? Are you using "database first" design? Then there might be the option to create a calculated column directly in the database which does the concatenation. You could map then this column to a property in your model (EF designer would create this property automatically) and queries should be possible. Hopefully also the QueryExtender would allow to use this field, but I am not quite sure.

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, I already have the database. So I have to somehow perform a concatenation of First_Name and Last_Name. I'm looking at using the CustomExpression option of QueryExtender, but thus far haven't been able to get it to work.

Comment: This is still very relevant and an easy way to get read-only properties set. You can't use them to query (because the fields aren't actually mapped to DB columns), but they make for ease of use when sorting and displaying data.